# What are the reasons for using AJAX over client-side jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

In contemplating my next asp.net site, where I am going to be dynamically generating href-laden html to display, I am unsure as to which approach to take -- I don't know yet wheter I will use AJAX and JSON (calling server-side code from jQuery in a .cshtml file to return JSON), or simply use jQuery to generate the html client-side.

A possible advantage of going with the latter, pure client-side jQuery approach would be, I would think,  performance, as the only trips to the server will be to retrieve non-local resources (images stored elsewhere that I will reference via hrefs).

Am I forgetting something/failing to take something into account, or am I right in reasoning that AJAX may be "overkill" or even less performant in my case?

Comment: Are you asking whether its better to send html to the client with an AJAX request rather than JSON, or are you asking whether it's better to use AJAX or to not use AJAX.

Comment: I would suggest you always generate the HTML client side. That way, you can hook up multiple clients to the same service, and allow each client to display the data however they wish.

Comment: The latter: simply call a jQuery function in a local .js file to dynamically generate and return the html to be created, or call a function in a .cshtml (server-side) file? I see no reason to NOT do the first, but I could be showing my ignorance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing it with javascript rather than server-side completely at that point?

Comment: @Kevin: I'm thinking it may be more responsive/"performant."

Comment: @crush: Interesting point; are you talking about maybe making the data available to subscribers, such as a "web service" type of scenario? If so, I hadn't thought about that, but it's a possible future feature.

Comment: If the server generates the html and sends it as a complete page, it will render faster and feel faster to the client as long as it doesn't impact load time significantly. Though, considering you're not using ajax to GET the data, i don't think doing it client-side vs server-side is going to make much of a difference, so i'd lean more toward serverside for that.

Comment: It all depends on what the content is and what it's purpose is. Is it something that everyone will use? Is it something that is hidden at the start but then shown later? Is it extra content that isn't important to the page? I'm beginning to wonder what your intent is for changing the way this content is served.

Comment: @Kevin: My intent? I simply want to dynamically generate content, based on data I will supply - a very common programming pattern. Only in this case (relatively new to me, hailing from the worlds of Delphi and C#), it's with jQuery, HTML, and CSS.

Comment: Right... but the best approach is going to depend on what the data is/does and how it's stored/generated/used.

Comment: @KevinB: The data is simple strings and URLs; I *might* store them in a database, but probably not. They will either be (if AJAX/JSON) members of a list, or (if jQuery) members of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in "C# 5.0 in a Nuts Hell" by the Albahari boys, in a section on asp.net on page 195 that, "*You can improve the interactivity and responsiveness, however, through client-side scripting or technologies such as AJAX*..."

So, I reckon my idea to go client-side may be best/most straightforward for my needs.